# JQL to get no of open issues on start day of week in past and no of closed issues at end day of that week

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jql

I am new to jql and puzzled on how to write jql query for this .

I want to get all open issues on start of N'th week in past and no of all issues closed by end of that week.

e.g . 3rd week in past , my week start day is monday morning and ends at sunday night. i want to get no of open issues on beginning monday morning , and no of all issues closed on end of the day sunday for that week

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `WAS` operator with an `ON` constraint like the following:

`status was open on "2020-01-01"`

Instead of a fixed date you can also use the JQL functions `startOfWeek()` and `endOfWeek`, but be carefull start of week and end of week may depend on the configured locale.